# Парсинг через selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Начал парсить через selenium (только начал), сделал скелет кода и у меня просто парсер ничего не выводит и я понятия не имею в чем проблема (может быть проблема банальная, но я просто еще не сильно в этом разбираюсь)

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    class EpicGamesStoreParser(object):
    
        def __init__(self, driver, lang):
            self.driver = driver
            self.lang = lang
        
        def parse(self):
            self.parse_el()
    
        def parse_el(self):
            self.driver.get("https://proghub.ru/tests")
            slide_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    
            for elems in slide_elements:
                print(elem.get_attribute('href'))
    
    
    def main():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        parser = EpicGamesStoreParser(driver, "python")
        parser.parse
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
```

вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]main()

Comment: `parser.parse` замените на `parser.parse()`

Comment: @RomanKonoval так работает, отлично